# "Cog" word's meaning doesn't follow in joint-word usages like "incognito" and "cognito" which refers to mind and knowledge

Tags: meaning, etymology, synonyms

I have observed some mistakes or maybe called blunders in the usage of word "cog" joined with letters to make words.

Though the words made or built by using the word cog like "incognito" or "cognition" deals with concepts relevant to mind and knowledge, there's not a single hint or form or slang in the list of "cog" word's meaning that suggests "brain" or "mind" as one of it's meaning or related meaning.

I have searched many popular online wikis and vocabularies but all failed to establish relation between cog and mind and still use the words "incognito" or "cognizance" to refer to mind-related scenarios.

Can someone clarify or shed light on this mistake and how it can be rectified ?

Comment: 'Cog' is not a root. 'Cognition' -> *co* + *gnoscere*.

Comment: Google `cognition etymology`.

Comment: And *cog* is from Middle English, probably related to Swedish *kugge* and Norwegian *kug*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root is not cog, but co+gno:

[Cognizance:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cognizance?ref=etymonline_crossreference)

> to know," from Latin cognoscere "to get to know, recognize," ***from assimilated form of com "together" (see [co-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/co-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + gnoscere "to know," from PIE root *[gno-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*gno-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to know."***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Oh I didn't knew about that, thanks.

Comment: To your list of "popular online wikis" you should add Etymonline.

Comment: PIE *_gno-_ is also the basis of English _know_. The original *g changed to k by Grimm's Law, and then later initial _kn_- clusters like the ones in _knife_ and _know_ dropped the stop and kept the nasal.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-on to [user121863's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/536095/75342), one must **constantly** remember that English is a **creole** (simplified mashup of) of Anglo-Saxon and French, with [**half** taken from Latin via Old French.  Another 10% is taken straight from Latin, and 20% from other languages](https://www.dictionary.com/e/word-origins/).

For example, "Fur" and "fury" are pronounced so differently because one is Germanic via Old French, and the other is Latin via Old French.  And "fir" is via Old Norse!!